# Изменение позиции элемента при клике

Tags: jquery, события, css

Есть такой блок:

```
<div id="block" style="bottom: 4%; position: absolute;"></div>
```

Такая ссылка:

```
<a href="#" id="menu">menu</a>
```

Нужно, чтобы при клике на ссылку, блок **#block** получил стиль "bottom: 10%" и при повторном клике обратно получил стиль "bottom: 4%"

Я сам написал прикольную штуку:

```
var _menu = $("#menu");
var _block = $("#block");
_menu.click(function () {
        if(_block.css('bottom', '4%'))
        {
            _block.animate({
                'bottom':'10%'
            },300);
        }
        else
        {
             _block.animate({
                'bottom':'4%'
            },300);
        }
    });
```

Ошибка в моем коде:  при вопторном клике на ссылку, блок получает стиль margin: 4% и сразу же получает обратно 10%; (спускается и поднимается).
Помогите решить задачу, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых, таким образом

```
_block.css('bottom', '4%')
```

вы устанавливаете значение **bottom**, а не читаете его.
Чтобы прочитать значение нужно опустить второй аргумент. Вот так:

```
_block.css('bottom')
```

Во-вторых, javascript вернет **вычисленное значение в пикселях**, а не в процентах.
В-третьих, использовать **inline-стили** вообще считается дурным тоном.

Прямого способа получить значение в процентах нет. Однако это не значит, что это вообще невозможно.

Самый простой (в плане кода) вариант, если значение **bottom** прописано как у вас в **inline-стилях**:

```
var _menu = $("#menu");
var _block = $("#block");
_menu.click(function () {
    if (_block[0].style.bottom === '4%') {
        _block.animate({
            'bottom': '10%'
        }, 300);
    } else {
        _block.animate({
            'bottom': '4%'
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

---

Вариант посложнее, который умеет считывать значение не только из inline-стилей, но и из обычных.

```
var _menu = $("#menu");
var _block = $("#block");
_menu.click(function () {    
    /* Высота нашего блока */
    var bH = parseFloat($('#block').css('bottom'));
    /* Высота родителя блока, по умолчанию берем высоту окна */
    var bParentH = $(window).height();
    /* Перебираем всех родителей нашего блока (уже отсортированы по близости) */
    _block.parents().each(function() {
        /* Высота элемента родителя */
        var elementH = Math.ceil(parseFloat($(this).css('height')));
        /**
         * Интересуют только те элементы, у которых заданы:
         * - относительное позиционирование
         * - высота
         */
        if ($(this).css('position') === 'relative' && elementH > 0) {
            bParentH = elementH;
            /* Выходим из цикла */
            return false;
        }
    });
    /* Значение из inline-стилей */
    var bInlineHInPercentage = _block[0].style.bottom;
    /* Автоматически рассчитываемое значение */
    var bCalculatedHInPercentage = Math.ceil(100 * bH / bParentH) + '%';
    /* Приоритет отдаем значению из inline-стилей, если таковое есть */
    var bHInPercentage = bInlineHInPercentage || bCalculatedHInPercentage;
    if (bHInPercentage === '4%') {
        _block.animate({
            'bottom': '10%'
        }, 300);
    } else {
        _block.animate({
            'bottom': '4%'
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

**[Вариант 1: позиционирование относительно всего документа](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/A8mh7/3/)**
**[Вариант 1: позиционирование внутри какого-то блока](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/A8mh7/2/)**
**[Вариант 2: позиционирование относительно всего документа](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/A8mh7/4/)**
**[Вариант 2: позиционирование внутри какого-то блока](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/A8mh7/5/)**

Comment: вот первый пример сильно упрощенный:

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/A8mh7/6/

Comment: [а вот без вмешательства в классы DOM](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/A8mh7/7/)

Comment: @eicto, отдельное спасибо за отличную идею! Надо будет запомнить этот трюк.

Comment: @VenZell, спасибо а какой именно вам понравился ? вот ещё так можно делать :) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/A8mh7/9/

Comment: @eicto, когда писал комментарий, мне был виден только первый вариант. На мой взгляд все хороши, но 2-й вариант и 3-й, как его логическое развитие, мне нравятся больше. :)

Comment: @eicto, @VenZell, спасибо большое! Для меня познавательно.

Answer (score 3):

А нельзя манипулировать классами: `.b4 {bottom: 4%} b10 {bottom: 10%}`

```
menu.click(function() {
  $('элемент').toggleClass('b4').toggleClass('b10');
});
```

Comment: Только надо не забыть про transition или css-анимацию (@keyframes). В исходном же вопросе переходы анимированы.